# Can use freenect library for ASUS Xtion

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
I am working with ROS turtlebot in ARM-based UDOO board, as I research, ROS Hydro support freekinect library for ARM, so I want to ask , can I use it for ASUS Xtion, because I think ASUS Xtion is more convenient than Kinect. So what should I do now?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113131/can-use-freenect-library-for-asus-xtion/) by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2013-12-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found one link in google group, there is one guy build successfully xtion and kobuki with raspberry Pi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAisDh1kngQ
I think it is as same as UDOO
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-turtlebot/R_QlqyGPLgk
I will try do it in this week.
In additionally, I think ros-hydro now have not enough supported features for ubuntuARM, so if any ones are excited about turtlebot and ARM, let try with ros-groovy and wait the new hydro update

---

Originally posted by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) with karma: 89 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1